# I need to send email to all user in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am working on a function to send emails to users, I already have my send mail function and it sends to a single user. I am trying to send to multiple users in an array now.

I am writing in Typescript and I am using mailgun as my email service provider

This is a sample send mail function:

```js
const data = {
  from: 'example@from.com',
  to: 'example@reciever.com',
  subject: 'Sample subject',
  html: await email(), // I am getting the email template here
}
await mailgun.messages().send(data)
```

With the code above, I am sending email to a single user. The json below shows how I am receiving the list of emails:

```
[
  {
    "name": "User 1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "user 2",
    "email": "user2@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

I want to be able to send to multiple users and I want to do it the smart way. Please suggest the best solution with code if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your suggestions?

Comment: Iterate through the array maybe? But I would like a smarter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `send` function is `async` and returns a promise:

```
async function sendMail(){
    const myRecipients = [
      {
        "name": "User 1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "user 2",
        "email": "user2@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
    const fromAddress = "my@email.address"
    // map our recipient array to the message format expected by `send`
    const myMessages = myRecipients.map(r => ({
        from: fromAddress,
        to: r.email,
        subject: "somesubject",
        html: "some html"
    }))
    // map our messages to a bunch of "in-flight" promises
    const promises = myMessages.map(m => mailgun.messages().send(m))
    // wait for all the promises to complete
    await Promise.all(promises)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js), which seems to have something called [mailing list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js#creating-mailing-list-members) which you possibly could utilize.  If not, then I would suggest that rather than simply iterating the users list and sending one email at the time (synchronously with await), trigger all emails to be sent asynchronously and then use Promise.all to know when all has been sent. Sample below is by no means tested (as i've never used mailgun) but it should give you an idea on how to implement it.

```
const users = [
  {
    "name": "User 1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "user 2",
    "email": "user2@gmail.com"
  }
];


const sendEmailToUser = async (user) => {
   const data = {
      from: 'example@from.com',
      to: 'example@reciever.com',
      subject: 'Sample subject',
      html: 'await email()'
   };
   await mailgun.messages().send(data);              
};

(async () => {
    const sendEmailPromises = [];

    for(const user of users) {
        // Start sending all emails
        sendEmailPromises.push(sendEmailToUser(user));
    }

    // Wait for all emails to be sent
    await Promise.all(sendEmailPromises);

    // Do something
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to iterate the data structure anyway.

```
var users = [
    {
      "name": "User 1",
      "email": "user1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "user 2",
      "email": "user2@gmail.com"
    }
  ];

users.forEach(function(user){
    name = user.name;
    email = user.email;

var data = {
    from: 'example@from.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Sample subject',
    html: await email(),
}    

await mailgun.messages().send(data);

});
```

Answer (score -2):

use a array map

i dont know about typescript.

you can get all elements like this

for ES6

```
user_list.map(user => console.log(user.name, user.email))
```

Comment: This is an abuse of `map` because it will create an unused array as its output. This is why `forEach` exists.

Comment: it could be better to enhance your code by using mailgun.messages().send(data) as user6601176 asked